# Old data are not deleted

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

On my sample project,I read data from a server,store them in sqlite and read them through a content provider. The data are displayed in a grid view. 
For example, I insert in my CMS a new image with its title and is shown. However,when I delete this image from my Server,and run the app again the deleted image is still there!!

This is my fragment where I use a loader.

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{
static public ArrayList<MyCity> cityList;
public String [] MY_CITY_PROJECTIONS = {MyCityContract.MyCityEntry._ID,
        MyCityContract.MyCityEntry.COLUMN_NAME,
        MyCityContract.MyCityEntry.COLUMN_ICON};

public final static int COL_IMAGE_ID = 0;
public final static int COL_NAME = 1;
public final static int COL_ICON = 2;

private static final String LOG_TAG = MainActivityFragment.class.getSimpleName();
public static MyCityAdpapter myCityAdpapter;
private static final int CURSOR_LOADER_ID = 0;
private GridView mGridView;

public MainActivityFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    // inflate fragment_main layout
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_activity, container, false);

    cityList = new ArrayList<>();

    myCityAdpapter = new MyCityAdpapter(getActivity(), null, 0, CURSOR_LOADER_ID);
    // initialize mGridView to the GridView in fragment_main.xml
    mGridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.flavors_grid);
    // set mGridView adapter to our CursorAdapter
    mGridView.setAdapter(myCityAdpapter);

    getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager();
    // initialize loader
    updateCityData();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    return rootView;

}
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(CURSOR_LOADER_ID, null, this);
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    switch (id) {
        case CURSOR_LOADER_ID:
            return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
                    MyCityContract.MyCityEntry.CONTENT_URI,
                    MY_CITY_PROJECTIONS,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null);
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("id not handled!");
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    myCityAdpapter.swapCursor(data);


}


@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader){
    myCityAdpapter.swapCursor(null);
}

public void updateCityData() {
    MyCitySyncAdapter.syncImmediately(getActivity());

  }
}
```

I read the json data and insert them in the sqlite in my SynAdapter

```
   public class MyCitySyncAdapter extends AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter {
   public static final int SYNC_INTERVAL = 60 * 180;
   public static final int SYNC_FLEXTIME = SYNC_INTERVAL/3;

   public String [] MY_CITY_PROJECTIONS = {MyCityContract.MyCityEntry._ID,
        MyCityContract.MyCityEntry.COLUMN_NAME,
        MyCityContract.MyCityEntry.COLUMN_ICON};

public MyCitySyncAdapter(Context context, boolean autoInitialize) {
    super(context, autoInitialize);
}

@Override
public void onPerformSync(Account account, Bundle bundle, String s, ContentProviderClient contentProviderClient, SyncResult syncResult) {
    cityList.clear();

    // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());

    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
    JsonArrayRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, API.API_URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
            //hidePD();

            // Parse json data.
            // Declare the json objects that we need and then for loop through the children array.
            // Do the json parse in a try catch block to catch the exceptions
            try {

                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject post = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    MyCity item = new MyCity();
                    item.setName(post.getString("title"));
                    item.setImage(API.IMAGE_URL + post.getString("image"));

                    ContentValues imageValues = new ContentValues();
                    imageValues.put(MyCityContract.MyCityEntry._ID, post.getString("id"));
                    imageValues.put(MyCityContract.MyCityEntry.COLUMN_NAME, post.getString("title"));
                    imageValues.put(MyCityContract.MyCityEntry.COLUMN_ICON, post.getString("image"));

                    getContext().getContentResolver().insert(MyCityContract.MyCityEntry.CONTENT_URI, imageValues);

                    cityList.add(item);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Update grid by notifying the adapter of changes
            myCityAdpapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            //hidePD();
        }
    });
    queue.add(jsObjRequest);
}


public static void configurePeriodicSync(Context context, int syncInterval, int flexTime) {
    Account account = getSyncAccount(context);
    String authority = context.getString(R.string.content_authority);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        // we can enable inexact timers in our periodic sync
        SyncRequest request = new SyncRequest.Builder().
                syncPeriodic(syncInterval, flexTime).
                setSyncAdapter(account, authority).
                setExtras(new Bundle()).build();
        ContentResolver.requestSync(request);
    } else {
        ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(account,
                authority, new Bundle(), syncInterval);
    }
}

/**
 * Helper method to have the sync adapter sync immediately
 * @param context The context used to access the account service
 */
public static void syncImmediately(Context context) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED, true);
    bundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL, true);
    ContentResolver.requestSync(getSyncAccount(context),
            context.getString(R.string.content_authority), bundle);
}

public static Account getSyncAccount(Context context) {
    // Get an instance of the Android account manager
    AccountManager accountManager =
            (AccountManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACCOUNT_SERVICE);

    // Create the account type and default account
    Account newAccount = new Account(
            context.getString(R.string.app_name), context.getString(R.string.sync_account_type));

    // If the password doesn't exist, the account doesn't exist
    if ( null == accountManager.getPassword(newAccount) ) {

    /*
     * Add the account and account type, no password or user data
     * If successful, return the Account object, otherwise report an error.
     */
        if (!accountManager.addAccountExplicitly(newAccount, "", null)) {
            return null;
        }
        /*
         * If you don't set android:syncable="true" in
         * in your <provider> element in the manifest,
         * then call ContentResolver.setIsSyncable(account, AUTHORITY, 1)
         * here.
         */

        onAccountCreated(newAccount, context);
    }
    return newAccount;
}

private static void onAccountCreated(Account newAccount, Context context) {
    /*
     * Since we've created an account
     */
    MyCitySyncAdapter.configurePeriodicSync(context, SYNC_INTERVAL, SYNC_FLEXTIME);

    /*
     * Without calling setSyncAutomatically, our periodic sync will not be enabled.
     */
    ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(newAccount, context.getString(R.string.content_authority), true);

    /*
     * Finally, let's do a sync to get things started
     */
    syncImmediately(context);
   }

   }
```

or you can have a look in project in [github](https://github.com/theo82/CustomProviderWithJson).

I am guessing that I should put `getContext().getContentResolver().delete` somewhere..

Please advice so i can delete record from sqlite,

Thanks Theo.

**EDIT**

Here is an interesting thing. I fixed the old data deletion problem! So far so good. However,when I turn off the wifi nothing is shown.

```
 @Override
public void onPerformSync(Account account, Bundle bundle, String s, ContentProviderClient contentProviderClient, SyncResult syncResult) {
    cityList.clear();
    deleteOldData();
    // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());

    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
    JsonArrayRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, API.API_URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
            //hidePD();

            // Parse json data.
            // Declare the json objects that we need and then for loop through the children array.
            // Do the json parse in a try catch block to catch the exceptions
            try {

                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {


                    JSONObject post = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    MyCity item = new MyCity();
                    item.setName(post.getString("title"));
                    item.setImage(API.IMAGE_URL + post.getString("image"));

                    ContentValues imageValues = new ContentValues();
                    imageValues.put(MyCityContract.MyCityEntry._ID, post.getString("id"));
                    imageValues.put(MyCityContract.MyCityEntry.COLUMN_NAME, post.getString("title"));
                    imageValues.put(MyCityContract.MyCityEntry.COLUMN_ICON, post.getString("image"));


                    getContext().getContentResolver().insert(MyCityContract.MyCityEntry.CONTENT_URI, imageValues);


                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Update grid by notifying the adapter of changes
            myCityAdpapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            //hidePD();
        }
    });
    queue.add(jsObjRequest);
}
 public void deleteOldData(){
    int deleted =    
     getContext().getContentResolver()
    .delete(MyCityContract.MyCityEntry.CONTENT_URI,
            null,
            null);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Movie Review Data Deleting, " + deleted + " rows deleted.");

}
```

And the logcat I get in the wifi - off mode is:

```
D/Volley: [1] 2.onErrorResponse: ContentValues
```

I repeat in online mode everything works perfect.

Comment: Well maybe your list hold the data. Try removing it from your list as well and call `notifyDataSetChange()`

Comment: I used notifyDataSetChange().

Comment: did you get whole response from server? like before Image delete and after Image delete

Comment: @Ganesh Pokale yes.

Comment: your custom `AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter` should only talk to your custom `ContentProvider`, not to some "static" data

Comment: @pskink. Please see my updated adapter. I insert ->delete and then insert the new data. It should work,but it doesn't:(

Comment: you are calling `cityList.add(item);` inside `onPerformSync`, this is what i am talking about

Comment: @pskink unfortunately,removing this doesn't solve the issue:(

Comment: Well that's a bit strange. The deleted picture is not shown in the gridview. But,I have to open and close the app few times.

Comment: did you remove that static field `cityList` storing the list?

Comment: Yes it is working now. But can't do anything when I am offline. The gridview is not displayed.

Comment: so `onLoadFinished` is not called or what? if it is, what does `DatabaseUtils#dumpCursor` show?

Comment: I get this 10-18 09:17:29.251 22393-22393/? D/Volley: [1] 2.onErrorResponse: ContentValues
10-18 09:17:29.271 22393-22393/? D/Volley: [1] 2.onErrorResponse: ContentValues

Comment: @ pskink please see my edit.

Comment: yes but the data are deleted.

Comment: `deleteOldData` inside `onResponse`, and not before calling `Volley.newRequestQueue`

Comment: yes! The syncadapter syncs every 5 seconds. After that period of time the data are deleted:).

Answer (score 0):

Before Image delete and after Image delete if you get whole response then instead of update SQLite Table, you need to Delete all data from SQLite Table and insert it again. This is good practice for offline caching

Before this code execute delete all data from SQLite table

```
try {
             // Clear Table before insert 
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject post = response.getJSONObject(i);
                MyCity item = new MyCity();
                item.setName(post.getString("title"));
                item.setImage(API.IMAGE_URL + post.getString("image"));

                ContentValues imageValues = new ContentValues();
                imageValues.put(MyCityContract.MyCityEntry._ID, post.getString("id"));
                imageValues.put(MyCityContract.MyCityEntry.COLUMN_NAME, post.getString("title"));
                imageValues.put(MyCityContract.MyCityEntry.COLUMN_ICON, post.getString("image"));

                getContext().getContentResolver().insert(MyCityContract.MyCityEntry.CONTENT_URI, imageValues);

                cityList.add(item);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

for example if you get this response

```
 "city" : [
{
    "value" : "city1"
},
{
    "value" : "city2"
},
{
    "value" : "city3"
}
]
```

you insert this in SQLite. and after this if "city2" delete you will get this response

```
"city" : [
{
    "value" : "city1"
},
{
    "value" : "city3"
}
]
```

and you start inserting using `insertWithOnConflict` but city1 and city3 get updated but what about city2

For this issue you need to delete all city data and insert it again

Comment: This is becoming really complicated. lol. I should do this inside my SyncAdapter?

Comment: I added this getContext().getContentResolver().delete(MyCityContract.MyCityEntry.CONTENT_URI,
                                MyCityContract.MyCityEntry._ID + " <= ?",
                                new String[] {post.getString("id")});

                        getContext().getContentResolver().insert(MyCityContract.MyCityEntry.CONTENT_URI, imageValues);

Comment: but with no result:(

Comment: please see the updated SyncAdapter in github. I did what you said. Insert->delete>insert.

Comment: this is complete project structure part.. So don't know exactly this will work or not. But It's better to delete data before start inserting

Comment: I think this will only delete only new response data.... Like city2 and city3 but still city2 is in database

Comment: database.delete(MyCityContract.MyCityEntry.TABLE_MY_CITY, null, null);                try something like this befor for loop start

Comment: But why should I delete from database,and not ask Content provider to do it?